# Failure to communicate with node.js server

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, server, socket.io

I have been following a tutorial on youtube , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppcBIHv_ZPs.
This tutorial shows how to setup up a basic server with socket.io and lets two people play the classic snake game.

After trying to setup communication  with the server and client, I have received errors in the developer console on the client  side.

The first error I received was

**127.0.0.1/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NfTLuxq' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

I then asked for help here and recieved good feedback about handling a cors error.
So I then searched up how to handle cors with socket.io and modified my code to
the following in my server.js file.

I modified my code from

```
const io = require('socket.io')();
```

to

```
const io = require("socket.io")( {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:8080",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});
```

However I am now recieving another error code as follows:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NfUXfLP' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.**

I thought once I allowed origin access as I understand it, I would be able to connect to port 3000 from the client side. Any help understanding this error would be greatly appreciated! Thankyou.

I then add credentials flag to my server.js file

```
const io = require("socket.io")( {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true
  }
});
```

and receive the first error again. This just does not want to work.

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NfUsnNV' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/' that is not equal to the supplied origin.**

Comment: remove the trailing slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number 0 and the “/“ are not the same, if you look at the string you want in NodeJS it ends with “/“ so remove it from yow cors contig, also always prefer localhost instead of 127.0.0.1. Localhost is treated as a secure domain

..........

copy and paste it

```js
/**
   WHAT EVER URL YOU SET HERE HAS TO BE THE EXACT SAME URL YOU PUT O N YOW BROWSER. SAME EXACT 


*/
const io = require("socket.io")( {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:8080",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true
  }
});
```

and on the browser paste `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: I switched it to localhost:8080 bur for some reason I get this error now. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'localhost:8080' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

Comment: Thanks your solution worked after I made it so both socket.io for the client and the server were the same.